# Iterate through folders and extract shapefiles to a geodatabase in python

Tags: merge, arcpy

Hi I am using sample data. In a folder called Shapefile, I have 3 folders; each one has 3 shapefiles named Hazard1.shp, Hazard2.shp, Hazard3.shp (there are about 3000 records in each). I am trying to iterate through each of these folders and extract Hazard1.shp from each folder and merge it into a feature class in a geodatabase called totals. This code is meant for hundreds of folders but I am using a sampling of 3. I run my code, with no errors but when I check totals there are only 3000 records - from the merge there should be 12,000. What am I doing wrong?

```
import os, arcpy.da

print os.getcwd()


for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for subdirname in dirnames:
        current_dir =  os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
        arcpy.env.workspace = current_dir
        fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Hazard1.shp")
        destination = r"F:\Extraction\GeoDatabase\Total.gdb\totals"
        for fc in fcList:
            print fc
            arcpy.Merge_management(fc,destination)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your 'totals' feature class each time you iterate a folder. You should either:

- create an empty list outside the loop and append fc to it each time you iterate, then merge all items in this list.
- Or, more simply, use `Append` instead of `Merge` (if 'totals' already exists).

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
Merge = r"F:\Extraction\GeoDatabase\Total.gdb\totals_Merge"
```

Then your for loop should be:

```
    for fc in fcList:
        print fc
        arcpy.Merge_management([fc,destination],Merge)
        arcpy.Delete_management(destination)
        arcpy.Rename_management(Merge, destination)
```